# How to force JWT auth for default GET endpoints of Wordpress rest api?

Tags: rest-api, security, authentication, endpoints

The default `GET` endpoints (for e.g. http://scintec.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/) of the Wordpress Rest api are public and can be accessed by anyone.

I am currently interacting with a Wordpress Rest api where I am using JWT authentication for `POST` requests.

I don't want my `GET` endpoints to be public and they should also require the JWT token in order to pass the request. How can this be done? I went through the documentation on this page https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/ but didn't find anything in this regard.

Also I am using the JWT Authentication for WP REST API plugin for JWT auth.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: No, the GET endpoints will always remain public.

Comment: @NavjotSingh Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74109621

Comment: @nico_lrx Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74109621